# Where I get net_rim_api.jar?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile-application

I'm working in J2ME environment for 6 months. In these 6 months I had done in j2me basics UI design including textbox, form, canvas, etc.

Now, my organization assign me a blackberry application. I fount that, "net_rim_api.jar" is need for developing blackberry application in j2me. But I don't know from where this jar is downloaded. So kindly tell me the link, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The net_rim_api.jar library is included with the BlackBerry JDE in the lib folder. You can download the JDE here http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp.

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse plugin `net_rim_api.jar` library is included in the below path :

C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\lib